# How to increment an array with a nested for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, increment, moving-average

There must be a more elegant way to do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < subsets.length-10; i++) {
    sample = (int)subsets[i];
    int y = (sample
             + ((int)(subsets[i+1])) 
             + ((int)(subsets[i+2])) 
             + ((int)(subsets[i+3])) 
             + ((int)(subsets[i+4])) 
             + ((int)(subsets[i+5]))) / 6;
}
```

Basically, it adds the next 5 values for 'subsets' incrementally. How to use a nested for loop to use a single formula that means I can increase how many times it adds the next value and then divide by that many also to get an average.

Something like?:

```
y = (sample + ((int)(subsets[i++n]))/n
```

where `n` is number of times it incrementally adds the next value

any ideas?

Comment: please define your subsets variable

Comment: The subsets variable is from a signal - I am building a sound visualiser graph. I have it working. I am just trying to smooth the signal by doing some averaging - using a moving average. But I want to be able to understand how each step works (I know there are some good examples of moving average algorithms - my problem is how to implement them - that is why I want to try to write from scratch...).

Comment: I mean define programmatically. Is is 1D, 2D, String, double ? Edit your code with the variable declaration before the loop.

Comment: it is a 1D Integer array which i convert to int

Answer (score 1):

sample is not special, it's only i+0 so you don't have to isolate it. You can try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < subsets.length-10; i++) {
    int y = 0;
    for(int j=i;j<i+n-1;j++) {
        y += (int)subsets[j];
    }
    y = y / n;
}
```

Comment: nice - and a nested for loop?

Comment: @twyeld it IS a nested for loop, ie, a loop inside another loop

Answer (score 1):

This Stream should give you all the `y` values:

```
IntStream.range(0, subsets.length - 10)
         .map(i -> Arrays.stream(subsets, 0, 6).sum() / 6);
```

You could also use `IntStream.average()` instead of calculating it yourself if a double is ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
y = Arrays.stream(subsets, i, i+6).sum()/6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of an nested loop is correct. Try something like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < subsets.length - 10; i++ )
{
   sample = subsets[ i ];
   int y = sample;
   for ( int k = i; k < i + 5; k++ )
   {
      y += subsets[ k ];
   }
   y /= 6;
}
```

Comment: ok i tried this and it gets close. But it doesn't return the right values. subsets is actually a float which gets converted to an int - maybe this is where the problem is? here is a selection of the returned values (yMave2 is correct):yMave2: 171 y: 180
yMave2: 197 y: 155
yMave2: 241 y: 129
yMave2: 254 y: 151
yMave2: 270 y: 191
yMave2: 287 y: 227
yMave2: 252 y: 245
yMave2: 195 y: 219
yMave2: 164 y: 175
yMave2: 165 y: 146
yMave2: 211 y: 131 I wonder if subsets is altered because it is inside the nested for loop twice?

Comment: @twyeld might be an 'off by one' mistake since I put in `int k = i;k < i + 5;k++` where 5 is a literal which might be replaced by 6. Depending on your desire. And no the subset is never altered, you just **get** values and do not modify them.

Comment: thanks, i tried changing the variables but still not returning the correct values...

Answer (score 0):

```
int sample;
        for (int i = 0; i < subsets.length - 10; i++) {
            sample = (int) subsets[i];
            for (int j = i; (j < i + 6) && (j < subsets.length -10); j++) {
                sample += subsets[i];
            }
            int y = sample / 6;
        }
```